# Problem with wrapping jqGrid column headers on IE

Tags: header, jqgrid, word-wrap

I'm using jqGrid in my pages, I modified the ui.jqgrid.css file to wrap the column headers like this:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    white-space: normal !important;
}

.ui-th-column,.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

It works fine in all of the browsers but IE! I tried IE7 and IE8 and the problem is still out there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to use additionally

```
.ui-th-div-ie {
    white-space:normal !important;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

**UPDATED**: It seems to me, that instead of all this styles it would be better to use one following:

```
th.ui-th-column div{
    white-space:normal !important;
    height:auto !important;
    padding:2px;
}
```

It seems work very good in all browsers. See an example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/scawa1952_.htm).

**UPDATED 2**: More information and more demos about the problem you can find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246506/how-to-wrap-single-column-header-text-into-multiple-lines-in-jqgrid/7256972#7256972).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
th.ui-th-column div{
    height:auto!important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
    white-space:normal !important;
    height:auto!important;
    padding:2px;
}
```

I tried Oleg's answer. But, though there was wrapping, height did not increase to fit the contents. So I modified the css as above and did work. I thought it will help someone out there like me. :)