# jqGrid column autosize

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to make a jqGrid column autosize so that the contents of a grid cell isn't cut off if it is too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "autosize" feature in the jqGrid, but you can use text wrapping in the grid cells (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994343/how-to-implement-wordwrap-on-jqgrid-which-works-on-ie7-ie8-and-ff)) and in the column headers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641400/problem-with-wrapping-jqgrid-column-headers-on-ie/3641561#3641561)).