# jqgrid- add scroll bar to long viewModel

Tags: css, view, jqgrid, model

I am using a jqGrid that has allot of columns to it.

I added the view option (when clicking on a row and then on the 'view' button, in the bottom left corner of the grid, it opens a model with all the info for that row.

I see that the model has some css style:

```
overflow-hidden
```

Therefor if i have allot of columns to show after a certain height that i gave it when creating the grid, they get hidden.

How can i make that dialog box be:

```
overflow-auto
```

If possible i want only the inside div to scroll and leave the header of the dialog and the buttons on bottom there all the time.

How can i do this?

```
myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
                { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, view: true }, //option
                {}, // use default settings for edit
                {}, // use default settings for add
                {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
                {},
                { height: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true} // view options
                );
```

I tried this:

```
$('#viewmod'+myGridId).css({overflow: 'auto'});
```

But it didnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for this.

When declaring the view options add the dataheight option...

```
{ dataheight: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true} // view options
```

Comment: Which sense has the posting of the question if you post your own answer 7 minutes later?

Answer (score 2):

You tried the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171924/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378666/315935).

Comment: @Ovi: You don't posted the grid which you use. It's unclear which types of data you have in the grid and in the view form. Setting of fixed `dataheight` solves only a part of problems. Event setting of `dataheight`, `height` and `width` based of `screen.height` and `screen.width` is not enough sometime (see referenced questions). At least I prefer to use `max-height` instead of `height`. Many people who has large grid makes different kind of optimization. For example one uses wrapping of texts, but for cells with `textarea` formatter and long data it could also be not enough. Look at the links