# In jqgrid,when mouseover a column heading,column heading will expand?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid,when i am keep a multiple column,scroll bar is coming in browser.i dont need a scrollbar.i have to fixed width for jqgrid.when i mouseover column heading will expand.below is screenshot of jqgrid.
[image]

Comment: The demo page which can be used to reproduce you problem can be more interesting as the screenshort. What exactly will be expanded on mouseover? At least two screenshort can clear that: one before mouseover and another after mouseover. In which web browser you have the issue? Moreover I don't imagine how the user can work with your grid having so many columns without having horizontal bar (you wrote: "i dont need a scrollbar").

Comment: when user mouseover a column heading that will expand, so user can see a column name.is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

First way which I can suggest you is to use [headertitles: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) setting of jqGrid. It will show tooltips with the full column texts.

The second way will be to use rotated column headers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490) for an example).

The third way is to use wrapping in the column headers: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641400/problem-with-wrapping-jqgrid-column-headers-on-ie/3641561#3641561) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246506/how-to-wrap-single-column-header-text-into-multiple-lines-in-jqgrid/7256972#7256972).

If the information from the cell contain is like chechboxes the user can have problem to find the column name if the user look at some cell in the middle of the grid. In such situations I would recommend you to set custom tooltip on the cells with respect of `cellattr`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405248/can-jqgrid-hover-text-be-defined-with-addrowdata/7408355#7408355) for details.

Comment: Thank you for give an idea,i will try this method.

Comment: @madhudev: You are welcome! Write at the end which way you decide to choose.

Comment: @madhudev: You are welcome! You should use more your voting up right. (currently you used it only once). It'is important to to other people to find the answer. The "accepted" answers not help here. Moreover you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the following simple rule: "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." It's common stackoverflow rule and I think you should know that this exists.

Comment: ok,i am new to stackoverflow,i wil proceed in future question.i make a voteup, thank you for your instruction.