# Change a Value of the columnModel JQgrid after draw

Tags: jqgrid, cell, param

when i draw the grid i have some column like this..

```
name: 'codigo', index: 'codigo', width: 50, align: 'center', editable: true }
```

But after i want to do a query and then set the editable option, for example to false, is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get *reference* to internal `colModel` using `getGridParam`:

```js
var colModel = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
```

Now you can enumerate elements in `colModel` array and find the element which has property `name` with the value `"codigo"`. After that you can modify `editable` property of the element of `colModel` array. Look at `getColumnIndexByName` function from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210627/315935) for a code example.

The most simple way to do what you want is the usage of [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("setColProp", "codigo", {editable: false});
```

Comment: Oleg, can you help me with another problem drawing data? Here is..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091661/wordwrap-in-a-cell-value-in-jqgrid
Thanks again!

Comment: @bombai: I read the question, but not full understand it. Do you use custom formatter which includes `<br/>` or you includes HTML fragments in the server response? Do you have any customization of CSS?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I include the <br/> between two values in the string of the server response. Not, i havent any customization by CSS, and i cant implement the white-space option of CSS because one or both values can contains white spaces..I hope that you understand me this time. Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me or only is possible by CSS? Thanks again!

Comment: @bombai: Loot at the following answers: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/315935), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3006134/315935), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3641561/315935). I hope that you can solve your problem by usage of CSS described in the answers.